# Sitecore Speak UI

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

I am using sitecore 8.2 (rev. 161221) and I am trying to learn Sitecore Speak UI.

I follow the steps describe [here](https://cmsview.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/sitecore-8-for-beginners-adding-custom-button-to-ribbon/) but the custom tab is not visible.

[image]

What I have created in core database

[image]

Let me know what I missed so that the new tab is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add at least one *Chunk* with some element, e.g. *Large Button*, to your Strip. Otherwise it's invisible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since the tutorial that I am reading is not updated. Do you have any recommendation on any reading materials? Sitecore documentation not good. Many things are skipped.

Comment: No, I'm not aware about any better source of documentation. Originally, I thought that this might be a CMS issue since, as a developer, I would liketo see the strip I've just added. From the other side there is a scenario which (IMO) can justify the current behavior. Imagine there is an Editor which has restricted access to most of the CE functionality (buttons/chunks/panels, all of that). Currently, the strips with all the restricted (hidden) buttons will disappear which looks correct to me.